# Are Optane PCIe 3.0 + 2282 cards compatible with older motherboards?

Tags: compatibility, nvme, optane

A lot gets written about Optane compatibility, and how it needs a current generation motherboard. But I can't find any reference to whether that's only for Optane directly plugged into RAM slots or used for booting.

When I research it, even [Intel's FAQ on Optane](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000024018/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html) just assumes it'll be used as a motherboard NVDIMM, RST chipset cache device  or bootable device. It doesn't say a word about data drive usage, and says nothing either way about other formats of XPoint 3D/Optane.

So what I'm trying to find out is a definitive answer whether Optane 2282 cards, and Optane full-size  PCIe 3.0 NVMe cards, are compatible with older generations of motherboard.

Also, if 2282 cards are compatible, can they be plugged directly into older motherboards with onboard 2282 slits, or mounted on PCIe with any normal + cheap 2282->PCIe adapter card?

I'd expect them to be as I expect them to have all needed controller/interfacing for both of these buses onboard (other than booting which I don't care about). I'd actually be surprised if they weren't compatible. But I don't want to spend money on one, unless I'm sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's now clear that Optane SSDs are 100% compatible with older chipsets and CPUs - guesses about CPU instruction sets are mistaken.

Over a year ago, [ServeTheHome.com tested running their entire website on Optane 900p SSDs](https://www.servethehome.com/intel-optane-a-practical-application-review/), to see what difference it made. They reported that

> *We put copies of the entire STH main site **on a dual Intel Xeon E5-2698 V4 system** that is identical to another system we have set up in the hosting cluster save that **this node had 2x Intel Optane 900p 280GB** AICs, 2x Intel DC P3600 1.6TB NVMe AICs, and 2x Intel DC P3700 400GB 2.5″ SSDs.....
>
> **We [did] a second day entirely on the Intel Optane 900p 280GB SSDs** [and tweeted] "The STH main site is **being served via ZFS mirrored Intel Optane 900p NVMe SSDs for a few hours today** just to generate some test data.."
>   — STH (@ServeTheHome) January 2, 2018*

What's interesting in this post is a throwaway comment -  the "v4" bit. [The Xeon E5-2698 v4 is a Broadwell EP CPU (LGA 2011v3)](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/processors/xeon/e5-processors/e5-2698-v4.html). *From that alone*, it's clear immediately that S.T.H. found Optane SSDs to be compatible enough, and stable enough, with Broadwell era  CPUs, to serve their entire site during testing, and to gain very positive impressions on the combination as well.

People have even reported getting Optane to work [on old Ivy Bridge 4790k motherboards running Windows 7](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/798147-optane-on-older-hardware/) - suboptimally for sure, but clearly no fundamental hardware incompatibility.

## tl;dr answer:

The limits on using Optane SSD like you'd use any other SSD, are apparently just the need for NVMe support (in the chipset+BIOS/UEFI+driver) and the lack of appropriate physical connectors, both of which are more likely to be missing as boards get older.

Very old versions of NVMe in the BIOS/UEFI might also need to be updated - there are hints about this in a couple of forum posts but no confirmation one way or the other so far.

- *(Relevant and not-well-known resource: [bios-mods.com](https://bios-mods.com) is a website that specialises in updating bios firmware modules for NICs, SATA, RST, USB, etc to newer versions, so the boards can be used with newer hardware, drivers or OSes, it could be helpful if stuck)*

The main reported issue in older chipsets/CPUs seems to be related to NVMe driver support (in Windows at least), which wasn't yet included in Intel RST at that time.

The requirement for a "latest CPU+chipset" only seems to apply if you want to use Intel's Optane-specific caching/acceleration/NVDIMM functionality, because that needs chipset support. But ordinary SSD use - apparently no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the same misunderstanding as in the post
[Can Intel Optane memory compensate for less RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1389552/can-intel-optane-memory-compensate-for-less-ram).
Read in that post why Optane "memory" is **not RAM**.

See also the video in
[How to Install and Manage Intel® Optane™ Memory in Windows® 10 (Basic)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023845/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)
to understand that an M.2 connector is required on the motherboard for Optane
and how to connect the Optane card to the motherboard.

Finally, you will find your answer in the Intel post of
[Where to Buy Intel® Optane™ Memory Ready Motherboards](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/optane-memory-ready-boards-where-to-buy.html).

But please note all the other requirements that are listed in
[Intel® Optane™ Memory: Before You Buy, Key Requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023994/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html).

(Personally, I don't see why anyone will buy Optane instead of investing in a
real SSD, but that's only my opinion.)

Comment: They do make Optane DDR4 NVDIMMs which apparently just act as persistent RAM (meant for servers I suppose).

Comment: None of this is relevant. A PCIe NVMe for very high speed data drive use will never be confused with RAM; M.2 is never "required" to plug in a PCIe NVMe; "where to buy" is a motherboard list,it doesn't explicitly answer whether or not Optane **PCIe cards** that are electrically compatible with old moboards can be used on them (it's just listing those natively usable for onboard caching/acceleration via the 370). As for the last comment, give it a break: I'm **already** using the fastest pre-Optane NVMe datacentre SSD on the planet (Intel P3700), tracing shows its I/O latency is the bottleneck.

Comment: @grawity: Optane RAM is slower than normal DDRn and only works on Xeon systems, not to mention that it isn't out yet and is likely to be prohibitively expensive for a home PC.

Comment: (Sorry grawity - that was a reply to @harrymc, not to you)

Comment: #Stilez: As long as you understand that Optane is *currently* only a cache to the disk, you may use it in suitable scenarios where you either read the same data multiple times or read your own written data. In any case, I don't see older motherboards as supporting M.2 NVMe. As remarked above, Intel publishes the entire list of requirements, so you can verify them for any specific motherboard. There cannot be any sweeping statement for *all* motherboards.

Comment: Harry - contrary to what you "don't see", I own not one, but >2< pre-Optane motherboards with native M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4/x2/x1 NVMe slots (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170-HD3P-rev-10#sp explicitly confirms, as does my http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z97%20Extreme6, many others exist too). You're not making a good case that you have done any fact-checking at all. All I see is inaccurate but widely held assumptions, including the laughable and dismissive throwaway that I "just" need to upgrade my Intel P3700 NVMe to a "real" SSD (!). If it was that clear I'd know the answer already.

Comment: Now you are talking specific motherboards that can be checked individually. In the [ASRock Optane supported list](https://www.asrock.com/feature/IntelOptane/) it says that you need an "Ultra M.2 slot" on the motherboard, which I suspect is marketing hype for an x4 slot. Both your motherboards have it, even if the Z97 is not in the ASRock list, but all requirements still need to be met, so go through the list. If afterward you decide to buy Optane, ensure the vendor has a no-question return policy if it doesn't work or the improvement is not that good.

Comment: Watch also the video in my link for how to attach the Optane to the motherboard, and verify that you have what's necessary, since not every motherboard has those connectors.

Comment: A concluding remark: You might think about investing in RAM, perhaps creating a RAM disk which will be much faster than Optane. Optane only goes up to 32 GB and that is not much - you can nowadays buy a larger SSD and use it as cache and this would give similar results ([link](https://www.wepc.com/tips/ssd-cache/)).

Comment: @harrymc, please please _please_ do even the most basic research before making posts like the ones you've made on this topic. Almost **nothing** you have written in comments above was correct, or not made worthless by wild mis-assumptions and condescension, over and again. That last post (about Optane "only going up to 32GB") is one more example: Optane 600p was available in 256GB in Summer 2016 - over 2 1/2 years before you wrote that misstatement. We're up to multi-TB now.

Comment: @Stilez: Not what Intel is advertising. And, yes, I check very carefully.

Comment: I can see how Intel is advertising Optane: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/gaming-enthusiast-ssds/view-all.html . Since when is a family of 280GB-1.5TB SSD devices "only going up to 32GB"? You didn't check a thing, even a quick glance - not on Intel's site, not on Amazon, not on tech sites. Please check carefully before posting misinformation.

Comment: Anyhow, see apparent correct answer now added.

Comment: If that's how you treat people that are trying to help you, I wonder what you do with your enemies. My answer is entirely correct: You need an M.2 connector on the motherboard. The rest is Intel confusion that led me to an outdated link on their website, but this is immaterial to my answer.

Comment: The OP asked about **"Optane full-size PCIe 3.0 NVMe cards"**. Intel sells a wide range of **PCIe Optane cards**. Even for M.2 there are **PCIe card adaptors**. If you don't have PCIe there are **M.2 USB3** adaptors too. Please _please_ yet again, research just the basics, before posting misinformation like _"you **need** an M.2 connector on the motherboard"_. You don't need that at all.

Comment: Yes, you may add it, so what. I'm tired of this endless discussion. I promise never to try and help you again. There, I hope you are happy now.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party and commenting on an old thread, but I wanted to throw my comment into the mix should anyone - like me - me looking up any of this info now in 2023 or in the future. I have a Dell PowerEdge R430 as my home server. I picked it up for cheap considering its age. It's a 13G server and I'm about to try some Optane drives and configurations to see how it responds. From reading others comments here, it seems that not only will it work but actually work quite well. It's too bad Intel's RST isn't like a downloadable software or something that you can employ on machines that don't seem to ship this from the factory, or have it built into the BIOS. For example, I configure Dell OptiPlex Micro 5000 series little PCs a lot for work, and there's some Intel RST stuff in the BIOS for those. I never looked at it much before but I am fairly certain that's where you would configure some if not all of your Optane drive settings. In addition to what I see in the GUI once Windows is all installed and booted up.

Then again, maybe this RST is available to download after all: [Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver Installation Software with Intel® Optane™ Memory (10th and 11th Gen Platforms)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html)

However, I believe the Broadwell chipset which the E5-26xx v3 and v4 series is "5th gen" and that link to Intel's RST stuff says 10th & 11th gen.

As others have mentioned here though, it seems that an Optane drive tech could be utilized with "older" motherboards like the one in my R430 which is LGA-2011 3